# how to avoid conflict in handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, templates, conflict, handlebars.js

handlebars.js has a powerful feature that is registerHelper. when different people use it together in a page, how to avoid function conflict?

```
eg

steve:

 Handlebars.registerHelper('getHeight', function(obj) {
      return obj.pic_height / obj.pic_width * 200 || 130;
  });

jobs:

 Handlebars.registerHelper('getHeight', function(obj) {
      return 120;
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`registerHelper` implementation](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/lib/handlebars/base.js#L13) is quite simple:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper = function(name, fn, inverse) {
  if(inverse) { fn.not = inverse; }
  this.helpers[name] = fn;
};
```

There's no checking if the helper has been defined already, the helper is simply written to the `Handlebars.helpers` object and that's that.

There's nothing stopping you from adding your own version of `registerHelper` that complains though. You could do something like this:

```
Handlebars.paranoidRegisterHelper = function(name, fn, inverse) {
    if(name in this.helpers)
        throw 'Someone is trying to redefine the ' + name + ' helper';
    this.registerHelper(name, fn, inverse);
};
```

Then using `paranoidRegisterHelper` twice with the same helper name would raise an exception.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/3Knj3/

If you wanted to keep using `registerHelper` as the name, then just safe a reference to it before you monkey patch it:

```
var registerHelper = Handlebars.registerHelper;
Handlebars.registerHelper = function(name, fn, inverse) {
    if(name in this.helpers)
        throw 'Someone is trying to redefine the ' + name + ' helper';
    registerHelper.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/hUu2r/